# Geometric representation of domain of $z=x+\sqrt{y}$

Tags: functions

I have to find the domain of this function and represent geometrically the domain in a three dimensional plan. The function is $z=x+\sqrt{y}$.

Now,the domain is $y\geq0$. How do I represent this?
How about the domain of $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}}$?

Comment: If I understood correctly, this is a function on two variables, so its domain is in a two-dimensional plane, not three-dimensional. Now draw the $xy-$plane, and think which points have non-negative $y$ coordinates.

Comment: No,I have to represent it geometrically.

Comment: @PedroMilet has given you a way to represent it geometrically, as a subset of the $xy$ plane. That is very much geometric.

Comment: Can you draw the domain in the default, two-dimensional setting (as Pedro Milet suggested)? Now redraw it as if it was lying flat on (infinitesimally thin, colorless) carpet in a room. In other words, add third dimension, so it looks more 'realistic'.

Answer (score 4):

I hope the following plots makes the problem a bit clearer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those are beautiful.

Comment: Somethimes, there's no substitute for "paper and pencil" (or pen)! +1

Comment: @amWhy: I SEE that. I've realized that. Don't worry. I think helping an student who is stuck in solving a problem; is much more sweeter than respecting others to me or to you. And I 've seen you have been like a hand for them here. Good Job Amy! ;-)

Comment: Thanks Babak: yes, helping is sweeter than all the rest. That's why I'm here. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Anyway, I thank you for your friendship. It's felt a little lonely on site were it not for your kindness, and the kindness of a few others. I just worry about whether I'm welcome now. But I am committed to education, and so it would be painful to depart from Math.SE. I hope I can sleep in peaceful slumber!

Comment: An original and unusual answer

Comment: @amWhy: I am glad, I could make you smile. Thanks Adi. :-)